# Open file dialog to select XML file

Tags: xml, vbscript

I have a VBScript that selects a file from the c: drive and gets the information from a tag on a XML file but I want the user to be able to select the file from a dialog but I cant seem to get it done, here is my script:

```
Dim xmlDoc, objNodeList, plot, fin

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
xmlDoc.load("C:\Users\User\Documents\vbscript\mlb.xml")
Set objNodeList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("league")


Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Create file
outFile= "C:\Users\User\Documents\vbscript\Leagues.txt"
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)



If objNodeList.length > 0 then
For each x in objNodeList
plot= x.getAttribute("name")

'Write to File
objFile.Write plot & vbCrLf

Next
Else
msgbox " field not found."
End If

objFile.Close
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows XP you can use `UserAccounts.CommonDialog` object, see documentation for more details but in short it's something like this:

```
Set dlg = CreateObject("UserAccounts.CommonDialog")
dlg.InitialDir = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("MyDocuments")
dlg.Filter = "XML files|*.xml"

If dlg.ShowOpen <> 0 Then
    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
    xmlDoc.load(dlg.FileName)
    ' Your code
End If
```

Note that I'm also using `WScript.Shell` object to get user's documents folder (so you don't have to hard-code it). I'd suggest to do same thing also for output file.

Unfortunately this object has been removed in Windows 7 (maybe because of security issues) then you have to use something else. There are many candidates, let's see some of them.

Easier method is to use `comdlg32.dll` like this:

```
Set dlg = CreateObject("MSComDlg.CommonDialog.1")
dlg.InitialDir = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("MyDocuments")
dlg.Filter = "XML files|*.xml"
```

This DLL seems to don't be registered on every system, if this is your case you have to [download it](http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?comdlg32) in c:\windows\system32 and register COM objects with `regsrv32`.

A decent alternative is to use `Shell` object (explore its methods on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774094%28VS.85%29.aspx)):

```
Set dlg = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set selectedFile = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "XML file:", &H00004000&, "C:\") 

If Not selectedFile Is Nothing Then
    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
    xmlDoc.load(selectedFile.Self.Path)
End If
```

That isn't a true *open file dialog* but a *browse for folder dialog* with files, better solution is to use [GetOpenFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), code is longer so please refer to [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1459/A-Filebrowser-for-VBA#xx1575872xx) for full source and details. In short you have to import that function:

```
Declare Function GetOpenFileName Lib "comdlg32.dll" 
    Alias "GetOpenFileNameA" (OFN As OPENFILENAME) As Boolean
```

You may also want to take a look to [this code on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/wangye/1932941), it handles most of tricky cases (yes such simple task isn't finally so simple!!!)

Comment: I get an error: ActiveX component can't create object 'UserAccounts.CommonDialog'

Comment: By the way I am using Windows 7

Comment: @RiquelmyMelara yes, it has been removed in Windows Vista, I added more examples (and well...actually a link to source code)